# Как объединить три массива в один?

Tags: php

У меня есть три массива.
Первый

```
array:6 [▼
  1 => "Угловая тумба"
  2 => "Тумба"
  3 => "Высокий шкаф"
  4 => "Угловой навесной шкаф"
  5 => "Тумба навесная"
  6 => "Высокий шкаф"
]
```

Второй

```
array:6 [▼
  4 => 1
  5 => 1
  6 => 1
  1 => 2
  2 => 2
  3 => 2
]
```

Третий

```
array:6 [▼
  1 => "corner"
  2 => "standard"
  3 => "twoBlocks"
  4 => "corner"
  5 => "standard"
  6 => "twoBlocks"
]
```

Как мне обьеденить значения.
Что бы ключь остался один 
А значения было слито в одно.
Типа

```
array:6 [▼
  1 => "Угловая тумба 2 corner"
  и тд ...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот.

```
   $combined = array_map(function($mass1, $mass2, $mass3) { return $mass1. ' ' . $mass2. ' ' .$mass3; }, $mass1, $mass2, $mass3);
```